# react textarea doesn't show new lines

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textarea

I have a question and I hope you'll know how to help me.

I have a **textarea** where I show my response from the backend.

Response is in this format:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  <j.0:Person rdf:about="https://create-profile.com">
    <j.0:homepage></j.0:homepage>
    <j.0:firstName></j.0:firstName>
    <j.0:based_near></j.0:based_near>
    <j.0:mbox_sha1sum>myemail-example@s.com</j.0:mbox_sha1sum>
    <j.0:lastName></j.0:lastName>
    <j.0:img></j.0:img>
    <j.0:schoolHomepage></j.0:schoolHomepage>
    <j.0:title></j.0:title>
    <j.0:skypeID></j.0:skypeID>
    <j.0:currentProject></j.0:currentProject>
    <j.0:publications></j.0:publications>
    <j.0:nick></j.0:nick>
    <j.0:weblog></j.0:weblog>
    <j.0:account>https://create-profile.com</j.0:account>
    <j.0:account></j.0:account>
    <j.0:workplaceHomepage></j.0:workplaceHomepage>
  </j.0:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

But, when I put it into the text area, I got something like this:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns# xmlns:j.0="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"><j.0:Person rdf:about="https://create-profile.com"> <j.0:homepage></j.0:homepage>
```

I tried to do something with css, new line etc but it doesn't work. It only works well if I send the response to div.

Can someone tell me how to have the same format of the response in a textarea?

Comment: Do you have option to fetch data in json format? How would you like your text to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from posting the data here what character code is separating your tags. From the sample output, it appears that it may just be spaces. In this case, you could try the code below. If it's not a space and you can determine what the separator is (e.g. '\r'), you could substitute it for the space character in the regular expression.

```js
// Example data with space as a delimiter
const data = `<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:j.0="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"> <j.0:Person rdf:about="https://create-profile.com"> <j.0:homepage></j.0:homepage> <j.0:firstName></j.0:firstName> <j.0:based_near></j.0:based_near> <j.0:mbox_sha1sum>myemail-example@s.com</j.0:mbox_sha1sum> <j.0:lastName></j.0:lastName> <j.0:img></j.0:img> <j.0:schoolHomepage></j.0:schoolHomepage> <j.0:title></j.0:title> <j.0:skypeID></j.0:skypeID> <j.0:currentProject></j.0:currentProject> <j.0:publications></j.0:publications> <j.0:nick></j.0:nick> <j.0:weblog></j.0:weblog> <j.0:account>https://create-profile.com</j.0:account> <j.0:account></j.0:account> <j.0:workplaceHomepage></j.0:workplaceHomepage> </j.0:Person> </rdf:RDF>`;

var regex = /> /g;
const formattedData = data.replace(regex,'>\n');;
document.getElementById('xml-data').innerHTML = formattedData;
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <textarea id="xml-data"></textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```